# Can't decide: PIC24 or PIC32

Tags: pic

I've been in the PIC-world for 12 years but only been using PIC10/12/16. For the next (one of-)project I will need a PIC with USB Host-mode, which means 24 or 32. Both architectures are ridiculously complex compared to the 8-bit baseline, so no matter which I choose I will have a lot to learn.

That said, what I want to do is to connect a USB keyboard to my device, retrieve the scancodes from the pressed keys, and then transfer the result to 20 output pins for a millisecond or two, clear all outputs, rinse and repeat. No screens, communications or other processing, just bitbanging the 20 output pins (using a truthtable of my own, depending on which keycode is grabbed from the keyboard).

This is just a very brief outline of the project, as I haven't figured out all the gory details yet. I might need 1-3 input pins for reset, calibrate, or whatever. Just in case. A 28-pin chip will probably not do since USB seems to require a bunch of pins itself, so I guess a 44-pin TQFP or similiar will do fine.

**Question:** Should I go for a PIC24 or a PIC32 here? What are the pros/cons of these two for my given scenario?

Comment: I think the PIC24 is a DSP-less version of the dsPIC which is designed in-house whereas the PIC32 is actually a MIPS core.

Comment: Could you get your hand on a PS/2 keyboard instead? That protocol is ridiculously simple to implement.

Comment: USB really only requires 3 pins, as long as you aren't doing USB 3+. The processor usually has D+, D-, and Vusb. A PIC24 should work just fine, and if you use MPLab and Harmony, it should be pretty simple to set up and program.

Comment: @janka I already made that one, that's why I want to ramp up the difficulty a bit. For the challenge.